# Is this sum of functions continuous? (involves characteristic function of rationals)

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem:** Given $f,g$ continuous functions over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\chi$ the characteristic function of the rationals ($x = 1 $ if $\quad x \in \mathbb{Q}$, and $x = 0$ otherwise), we define $h$ as:
$$h = \chi f + (1-\chi) g$$

**In which points is h continuous?**

- My approach is the following:

We know that $\chi$ is not a continuous function over $\mathbb{R}$. It is also important to note that, $\forall x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, we know that $\lim_{x \ \to x_0 } h(x_0)$ can be approached by either rational or irrational numbers.
Therefore, taking into account the behaviour of $\chi$, $h(x_0)$ will only be continuous at $x_0$ if $f(x_0) = g(x_0)$ (remember $f,g$ are continuous).

Is my reasoning coherent?

Thanks.

Comment: @Tuvasbien I think that in this problem you have to seek a "sufficient" condition that makes h continuous, because otherwise it would not make sense, as you have mentioned.

Comment: Then $h$ is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$ as you've mentioned.

Comment: I'd say your argument is the right intuition, but far from rigorous.

Comment: I'd try to show that if $p(x)$ is continuous then $\chi(x)p(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$ iff $p(x_0)=0,$ then prove your result using the first part as a lemma.